# How to generate graph from SQL Server database?

Tags: schemacrawler

I'm trying to generate a graph of SQL Server tables. For some reason `-command=graph` and `outputformat=pdf` are not working.

I was able to generate the HTML report when I run with `-command=schema` but `command=graph` is not even working.

```
_schemacrawler>schemacrawler.cmd -server=sqlserver -host=sqlserver -port=1433 -database=test -schemas=test\..* -user=test -password=******** -command=graph -noinfo -infolevel=standard -routines= -infolevel=maximum -tabletypes=TABLE -grepcolumns=.*\.TestID -only-matching -outputformat=pdf -outputfile=graph.pdf -loglevel=CONFIG
```

Output:

```
Jan 16, 2019 3:12:09 PM schemacrawler.tools.executable.SchemaCrawlerExecutable execute
INFO: Executing command <graph> using <schemacrawler.tools.executable.CommandDaisyChain>
Jan 16, 2019 3:12:09 PM schemacrawler.tools.text.operation.OperationCommand execute
INFO: Output format <pdf> not supported for command <graph>
```

Comment: BTW, I'm able to generate the diagram using the following command,             
C:\schemacrawler15.03.04stribution\_schemacrawler>schemacrawler.cmd -server=sqlserver -host=sqlserver port=1433 -user=test -password=***** -database=test -schemas=test\.(?:(?!sys).)* -infolevel=maximum -routines= -tabletypes=TABLE -parents=1 -children=1 -only-matching -command=schema -outputformat=svg  -outputfile=ods_database-diagramrelation.svg %* -loglevel=CONFIG                                                                                                                      so outputformart=SVG worked

Comment: So do you not have the issue any more? You may want to write an answer so the next person can find the solution.

Comment: Still not able to generate a graph in pdf. command=graph and outpuformat=pdf not working.

Comment: Use `-command=schema`

Comment: -command=schema has been working with only PDF output.

Comment: Please follow http://www.schemacrawler.com/consulting.html